# problem running docker image using jupyter notebook

Tags: python, docker, jupyter-notebook

I have a jupyter notebook and a data file in a folder. I made a Dockerfile and wrote the following lines

```
FROM jupyter/base-notebook

ARG export_file=FooD_Kind.csv

RUN pip install jupyter

RUN pip install numpy

RUN pip install matplotlib

RUN pip install pandas

RUN pip install pulp

COPY $export_file FooD_Kind.csv

COPY task_4kind.ipynb /

CMD ["jupyter notebook", "task_4kind.ipynb"]
```

I can successfully build an image using `docker build -t nameofimage` But when I do `docker run -it nameofimage`. I get an error `[FATAL tini (7)] exec jupyter notebook failed: No such file or directory` .

How do I run this jupyter notebook in docker?

EDIT:

I tried two replacements on the last line,
I replaced the last line with

```
# Start the jupyter notebook
ENTRYPOINT ["jupyter", "notebook", "--ip=*"]
```

It runs and gives a token on the screen but when I paste the token on localhost, It gives invalid credentials error

then I replaced the last line with

```
CMD jupyter notebook --port=8888 --no-browser --ip=0.0.0.0 --allow-root
```

It runs and gives a token on the screen but when I paste the token on localhost, It gives invalid credentials error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you check the [original Dockerfile](https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/blob/master/base-notebook/Dockerfile), you will find the following;

```
ENTRYPOINT ["tini", "-g", "--"]
CMD ["start-notebook.sh"]

# Add local files as late as possible to avoid cache busting
COPY start.sh /usr/local/bin/
COPY start-notebook.sh /usr/local/bin/
COPY start-singleuser.sh /usr/local/bin/
```

`start-notebook.sh` will get you a valid token. Subsequent files allow to interact with the image, these options are described in the [docs](https://jupyter-docker-stacks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using/common.html).

Mind that there are more caveats, e.g. which user is running commands described in Dockerfile: `root` or  `jovyan` (Jupyter user)? Commands executed by root may set permissions in a way that won't allow `jovyan` to e.g. load given package. To fix this, there's an extra line in all Jupyter (base notebook and derived) Dockerfiles:

```
RUN fix-permissions /etc/jupyter/
```

[Here](https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/blob/master/minimal-notebook/Dockerfile) is an example how a derived notebook could look like.

In essence, either remove your custom ENTRYPOINT / CMD and use the original ones or make sure you e.g. get the token right. Also, fix permissions.

Comment: I get the following error, `Step 13/17 : COPY start.sh /usr/local/bin/

COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder157048403/start.sh: no such file or directory`

Comment: If you use `jupyter/base-notebook` then  `start.sh` is already there. Besides, always check if the file you want to copy is there in the first place.

Comment: `ARG BASE_CONTAINER=jupyter/base-notebook

FROM $BASE_CONTAINER
ARG export_file=FooD_Kind.csv
RUN pip install numpy
RUN pip install matplotlib

RUN pip install pandas

RUN pip install pulp

RUN fix-permissions /etc/jupyter/

COPY task_4kind.ipynb /



COPY $export_file FooD_Kind.csv

COPY task_4kind.ipynb /

# Add local files as late as possible to avoid cache busting

COPY start.sh /usr/local/bin/

COPY start-notebook.sh /usr/local/bin/

COPY start-singleuser.sh /usr/local/bin/

ENTRYPOINT ["tini", "-g", "--"]

CMD ["start-notebook.sh"]` is this correct?

Comment: No. You already have the jupyter files you try to copy. Also, no need to modify the CMD or ENTRYPOINT. Check the example I linked.

Comment: `ARG BASE_CONTAINER=jupyter/base-notebook

FROM $BASE_CONTAINER

MAINTAINER khan saab "dskhanirfan@gmail.com"

ARG export_file=FooD_Kind.csv

RUN pip install numpy

RUN pip install matplotlib

RUN pip install pandas

RUN pip install pulp

RUN fix-permissions /etc/jupyter/


ENTRYPOINT ["tini", "-g", "--"]

CMD ["start-notebook.sh"]` I can successfully build an image but the token is still giving invalid credentials error on localhost

Comment: Again, you *don't need* to put ENTRYPOINT or CMD. It's done for you in the base image. You should spend some time trying to understand how Dockerfile works. Also, use e.g. gists or repository to share the code, don't paste anything long in comments. Here's a Dockerfile gist I made for you:https://gist.github.com/tracek/44ab85770e36a59afd91775e7d4949b0 I am using pip only because you did. I'd stick to conda.